Coleman home furnace 7900 blower issue
When my Coleman home furnace series 7900 burner comes on, the blower motor comes on at low speed causing a upper resettable limit switch trip.
If I turn the thermostat off the moment the blower starts, the burner turns off.  Then, after a few seconds, the blower comes on at normal speed and cools down.
If I then turn the thermostat back, on the burner starts and the fan starts as it should and runs at normal speed.
